# Representations of finite groups over different algebraically closed fields

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, $K_1,K_2$ are two algebraically closed field and $(\text{char}K_i,|G|)=1$. What's the relationship between irreducible representations over $K_i$? ($i=1,2$)

The number of irreducible representations are the same ($=$number of conjugacy classes of $G$). Does there exist a bijection between irreducible representations over $K_i$ which preserves dimesnion and is functorial respect to $G$ ? Meanwhile, can we put other restrictions such that such bijection is unique?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{|G|},\mu_m]$ where $m=\exp G$ is the exponent of $G$ and $\mu_m$ is the set of the $m$th roots of unity. The idempotents in the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ (corresponding to projections onto isotypical components, and are the identity elements of the summands in the Artin-Wedderburn decomposition) are in fact elements of $R[G]$, as they are given by $e_{\small V}=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi_{\small V}(g^{-1})g$.

By fixing (onto) quotient maps $R\to K_1$ and $R\to K_2$ we get corresponding idempotents in the group algebras $K_1[G]$ and $K_2[G]$ corresponding to the irreps over *those* fields. This induces a bijection (which should be functorial in some sense?) but it depends on the original choice of quotient maps from $R$ which are all related by automorphisms of $K_1$ and $K_2$.